# Update ImageSource when button clicked

Tags: c#, xaml

When I load and populate my `ListBox`, I check whether a `bool` value is `true` or `false`, and depending on that `bool` I want to bind the current image (liked.png or notliked.png).

Button within Listbox:

```
<Button Click="LikePost">
    <Button.Background>
        <ImageBrush Stretch="Uniform" ImageSource="{Binding imagesource}"/>
    </Button.Background>
</Button>
<Image Source="liked.png" Visibility="collapsed"/>
<Image Source="notliked.png" Visibility="collapsed"/>
```

(Only when those last two lines are there, the images show???)

I have the following class assigned to the listbox:

```
public class Item : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string value1 { get; set; }

    public event System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private System.Windows.Media.ImageSource _imagesource;
    public System.Windows.Media.ImageSource imagesource
    {
        get { return _imagesource; }
        set
        {
            if (_imagesource == value) return;
            _imagesource = value;
            NotifyLikeImageChanged("like");
        }
    }
    private void NotifyLikeImageChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

In my LikePost functions I check whether or not the post is liked and change the imagesource in my class accordingly. But the image won't change?

Comment: Do you have access to this file ? and why `Absolute` and not `RelativeOrAbsolute`

Comment: The files are in my root. When I use "Absolute" I get 'System.UriFormatException'.

Comment: `UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute`

Comment: Sorry didn't read your answer correctly. When I use RelativeOrAbsolute no image shows.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

If your silverlight app is under /ClientBin folder, the url should be relative to the ClientBin. So if your image locates directly under your web app, you can try new Uri("../path.png", UriKind.Relative).

You can also use fiddler or chrome developer tools (Network tab) to capture your image request, which will show you the url you are requesting for.